# Error when using resolve with http requests in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, observable

I am trying to use resolve for prefetching a http request in my Angular 4 project, but its throwing a `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Response with status` whenever there is an error response from Node server. The code works fine when there is a success http code like 200. Here's the `resolve` code I am working on:

```
@Injectable()
export class LoginResolverService implements Resolve<Object> {

  constructor(private http: Http) {
  }

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<Object> | Promise<Object> | Object {
    const headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/login_check', {headers: headers})
      .map((response: Response) => {
        return response.json();
      }).catch((error: Response) => Observable.throw(error.json()));
  }
}
```

Component file code:

```
loginState: Observable<Object>;
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.data.subscribe((data: Data) => {
      this.loginState = data['isLoggedin'];
      this.loginState.subscribe((response: any) => {
        console.log(response);
      }, (error: any) => {
        console.log(error)
      })
    });
  }
```

Routes related code:

`{path: 'notifications', loadChildren: './notifications/notifications.module#NotificationsModule', resolve: {isLoggedin: LoginResolverService}}`

Please help me solve this issue, as I couldn't find any proper information about using `resolve` with `http`

Comment: It seems fine. Where do you subscribe to it?

Comment: @echonax I couldn't subscribe as I am returning an object

Comment: You are returning an **Observable** whose response is an **Object**. `this.http.get` returns an observable

Comment: @echonax If I try to subscribe it in the component file, I am getting an error as `'subscribe' doesn't exist on type 'Object'`. Here's the code I am using in my component file `this.route.data.subscribe((data: Data) => {
      this.loginState = data['isLoggedin'];
      this.loginState.subscribe((response: any) => {
        console.log(response);
      }, (error: any) => {
        console.log(error)
      })
    });`

Comment: It's a typchecking issue. Remove `| Object` and `| Promise<Object>` parts from your methods return type. And if you are going to add code, add it to your question please not in the comment section.

Comment: @echonax Even if i subscribe it in my component file, `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): [object Object]` error keeps on coming up

Answer (score 0):

In my resolver service, I call a separate data service to actually get the data:

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<IProduct> {
    let id = route.paramMap.get('id');
    if (isNaN(+id)) {
        console.log(`Product id was not a number: ${id}`);
        this.router.navigate(['/products']);
        return Observable.of(null);
    }
    return this.productService.getProduct(+id)
        .map(product => {
            if (product) {
                return product;
            }
            console.log(`Product was not found: ${id}`);
            this.router.navigate(['/products']);
            return null;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(`Retrieval error: ${error}`);
            this.router.navigate(['/products']);
            return Observable.of(null);
        });
}
```

Then in the component:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.product = this.route.snapshot.data['product'];
}
```

That's it!

Or if you expect that the resolved data property will change without changing the route (not including user edits to that data), then you can use:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.data.subscribe(data => {
         this.product = data['product'];
    });
}
```

The router itself calls the resolver and handles the subscription. So you don't have to.